# Tabs are displayed one after the other

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php page that contains an accordion menu that is used to toggle tabs and my first tab has form(say search-form)  and  a div(say search-result) to which content is added dynamically

when the page loads everything is fine but when i navigate to another tab it is displayed after the first tab and the first one not fading out

can anyone tell me whats happening
thanks in advance

here is my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Ashtapathi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ahstapathi_style.css"  />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
   function show_category(str)
   {
    if(str=="")
    {
     document.getElementById("cat_select").innerHTML="";
     return;
    }
    else
    {
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
     {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
      {
       document.getElementById("cat_select").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
     };
     xmlhttp.open("GET","admin/cat_select.php?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
    }
   }
   
   function show_type(str)
   {
    if(str=="")
    {
     document.getElementById("type_select").innerHTML="";
     return;
    }
    else
    {
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
     {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
      {
       document.getElementById("type_select").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
     };
     xmlhttp.open("GET","admin/type_select.php?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
    }
   }
   
   function show_plan(str)
   {
    if(str=="")
    {
     document.getElementById("plan_select").innerHTML="";
     return;
    }
    else
    {
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
     {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
      {
       document.getElementById("plan_select").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
     };
     xmlhttp.open("GET","admin/plan_select.php?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
    }
   }
   
   function search_category(str)
   {
    if(str=="")
    {
     document.getElementById("search-result-area").innerHTML="";
     return;
    }
    else
    {
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
     {
      req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     req.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
      if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
      {
       document.getElementById("search-result-area").innerHTML=req.responseText;
      }
     };
     req.open("GET","search/category_search.php?q="+str,true);
     req.send();
    }
   }
   
   function search_type(str)
   {
    if(str=="")
    {
     document.getElementById("search-result-area").innerHTML="";
     return;
    }
    else
    {
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
      req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
     {
      req1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     req1.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
      if(req1.readyState == 4 && req1.status == 200)
      {
       document.getElementById("search-result-area").innerHTML=req1.responseText;
      }
     };
     req1.open("GET","search/type_search.php?q="+str,true);
     req1.send();
    }
   }
   
   function search_plan(str)
   {
    if(str=="")
    {
     document.getElementById("search-result-area").innerHTML="";
     return;
    }
    else
    {
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
      req2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
     {
      req2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     req2.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
      if(req2.readyState == 4 && req2.status == 200)
      {
       document.getElementById("search-result-area").innerHTML=req2.responseText;
      }
     };
     req2.open("GET","search/plan_search.php?q="+str,true);
     req2.send();
    }
   }
  </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
   
    <?php
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","flat");
   $res=$mysqli->query("select * from floor where status = '1'");
  ?>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
         <?php require_once("includes/sidebar-accordion.php");?>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
         <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
              <h1 align="center">Search</h1>
              <div class="row" align="center">
              
                <form class="form-inline form-search" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" onchange="show_category(this.value);search_category(this.value);">
                     <option>Select Floor</option>
                      <?php
                         while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
             {
            ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row['f_id']; ?>">
                             <?php echo $row['f_name']; ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php
             }
            ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" id="cat_select">
                    <select class="form-control">
                     <option>Select Category</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" id="type_select">
                    <select class="form-control">
                     <option>Select Type</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </form>
                
              </div>
              <div style="width:100%;" id="search-result-area">
                <?php
                  $count=0;
                  $q_res=$mysqli->query("select * from floor where status = '1'");
                  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q_res))
                  {
                    if($count==3)
                    {
                      echo "</div>";
                      $count=0;
                    }
                    if($count==0)
                    {
                      echo "<div class=row>";
                    }
                    echo "<div class=col-sm-4>";
                      echo "<div class=search-list>";
                        echo "<h5>";
                          echo $row['f_name'];
                        echo "</h5>";
                        if($row['status']==1)
                        {
                          echo "<small class=text-success>";echo "Available";echo"</small>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          echo "<small class=text-danger>";echo "Available";echo"</small>";
                        }
                      echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    $count++;
                  }
                ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
              <h1>ios</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
              <h1>jmeter</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
              <h1>ejb</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

here is my accordin menu that i have included in my page(sidebar-accordion.php)

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-primary">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="sidebar">
        <div class="nav">
          <div class="panel-group navbar-collapse" id="accordion">
        
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
                    Content
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div><!--class="panel-heading"-->
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>News</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>Newsletters</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>Comments</a>
                        <span class="badge">42</span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div><!--class="panel-body"-->
              </div><!--id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"-->
            </div><!--class="panel panel-default"-->
            
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
                    Content
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div><!--class="panel-heading"-->
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Articles</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>News</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>Newsletters</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>Comments</a>
                        <span class="badge">42</span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div><!--class="panel-body"-->
              </div><!--id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"-->
            </div><!--class="panel panel-default"-->
            
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
                    Content
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div><!--class="panel-heading"-->
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Articles</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>News</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>Newsletters</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>Comments</a>
                        <span class="badge">42</span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div><!--class="panel-body"-->
              </div><!--id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"-->
            </div><!--class="panel panel-default"-->
            
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
                    Content
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div><!--class="panel-heading"-->
              <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Articles</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>News</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>Newsletters</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>Comments</a>
                        <span class="badge">42</span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div><!--class="panel-body"-->
              </div><!--id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"-->
            </div><!--class="panel panel-default"-->
            
          </div><!--class="panel-group" id="accordion"-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div><!--row-->
```

css (style.css)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.content
{
  padding-top:20px;
}

.dynamic-content
{
  padding-right:20px;
}

.content h1
{
  text-align:center;
}

.dynamic-content form
{
  padding:0px 15px !important;
}

.side-menu
{
  background-color:#337ab7;
  color:#FFF;
  padding:10px 1px !important;
  margin:0px;
}

@media(max-width:767px)
{
  .side-menu
  {
    margin-left:-30px !important;
    margin-right:-30px !important;
  }
}

.side-menu .nav li a
{
  color:#FFF !important;
  background-color:337ab7 !important;
  border-radius:0px;
  margin:0px !important;
}

.side-menu .nav li a:hover,
.side-menu .nav li a:focus
{
  color:#337ab7 !important;
  background-color:#FFF !important;
}

.side-menu .navbar-collapse
{
  padding:0px !important;
}

@media(max-width:767px)
{
  .side-menu .navbar-collapse
  {

    margin-top:10px !important;
  }
}

.side-menu  .navbar-header .navbar-toggle
{
  background-color:transparent;
  margin:0px 10px;
  padding:0px;
}

.side-menu  .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar
{
  background-color:#FFF;
}

.navbar-primary
{
  margin-top:15px !important;
  margin-left:0px !important;
  margin-right:0px !important;
  min-height:30px !important;
}

@media(max-width:767px)
{
  .navbar-primary
  {
    background-color:#222;
   color:#9d9d9d;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    margin-left:-15px !important;
    margin-right:-15px !important;
    left:0 !important;
    right:0 !important;
  }
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-header .navbar-toggle
{
  border:none;
  padding:0px !important;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-primary .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus
{
  background-color:transparent !important;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar
{
  background-color:#9d9d9d;
  max-height:2px;
  height:2px;
  margin:3px;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse
{
  padding:0px !important;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px !important;
  background-color:transparent;
  color:#9d9d9d;
  border:none !important;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel
{
  border:none !important;
  margin:0px !important;
  background-color:transparent;
  color:#9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-heading
{
  background-color:transparent;
  color:#9d9d9d;
  border:none !important;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-heading a
{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-heading a:hover,
.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-heading a:focus
{
  color:#FFF;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-heading a .glyphicon
{
  margin-right:10px;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-body
{
  border-top:1px solid #555;
  border-bottom:1px solid #555;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-body table
{
  margin-bottom:0px;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-body table tr td
{
  border:none;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-body table tr td a
{
  background-color:transparent;
  color:#9d9d9d !important;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-body table tr td a .glyphicon
{
  margin-right:10px;
}

.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-body table tr td a:hover,
.navbar-primary .navbar-collapse .panel-group .panel .panel-body table tr td a:focus
{
  color:#FFF !important;
}

.form-search
{
  width:100%;
  margin-top:0px !important;
  margin-bottom:20px !important;
  margin-left:0px !important;
  margin-right:0px !important;
}

@media(max-width:767px)
{
  .form-search
  {
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:15px !important;
  }
}

.form-search .form-group
{
  width:30%;
}

@media(max-width:767px)
{
  .form-search .form-group
  {
    width:100%;
  }
}

.form-search .form-group .form-control
{
  width:100%;
}

.btn-inverse
{
  background-color:#222 !important;
  color:#9d9d9d;
  height:35px;
}

.btn-inverse:hover,
.btn-inverse:focus
{
  color:#FFF !important;
}

.small-visible
{
  display:none;
}

@media(max-width:767px)
{
  .small-visible
  {
    display:inline-block;
  }
}

#myTabContent .tab-pane
{
  padding:0px !important;
}

@media(max-width:767px)
{
  #myTabContent .tab-pane
  {
    padding-left:10px !important;
    padding-right:10px !important;
  }
}

.search-list
{
  border:1px solid #222;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
}

@media(max-width:767px)
{
  .search-list
  {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
  }
}

.search-list h5
{
  color:#222 !important;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.search-list small.text-success
{
  color:#090 !important;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.search-list small.text-error
{
  color:#F00 !important;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```